# Firestore: Avoid overriding security rule via firebase-admin

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, firebase-admin, google-cloud-firestore

I have some scripts on nodeJS to fill my database but they seem to ignore the security rules written in the `firestore.rules` file. The rules work fine when using the app as a authenticated user but ignored via the firebase-admin package.

With the Realtime database we had `databaseAuthVariableOverride` but it's ignored for Firestore apparently.

See the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges

Is there a way to prevent firebase-admin from uploading malformed/false datas ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: An alternative method of authentication is explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079664/how-to-use-admin-sdk-with-limited-privileges-on-firestore