# Restrict firestore access to admin-sdk

Tags: node.js, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am designing an application (let's call it a TodoList app) based on **VueJs** (for the *UI*) + **NodeJs** (for the *backend*, which will run in Google Cloud Platform) + **Firestore** (for the *auth + database*).

I have wandered through the huge documentation of Google (sometimes redundant!) to achieve something that should work but I am not sure it's production-proof.

**Situation:**

- A user has signed-in on my VueJs app thanks to the password-based authentication of Firebase (and the user's credentials, including his accessToken, are stored in my Vuex store).
- The Firebase Admin SDK is running on my backend.
- My VueJs app is requesting my backend.
- The backend [verifies the accessToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) sent in the client-side request
- It is my backend that request my Firestore database thanks to the Admin SDK

I have set some security rules on my Firestore database:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

so that I don't want any logged users to access data from another user.

**Question:**

As the Firebase Admin SDK has full privilege on my Firestore database, how can I make sure there won't be any security issues. For now, I am just verifying the accessToken sent in the request to my backend, but ... something makes me feel wrong with this!

**Code:**

On client-side:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // Save the user credentials
  }
}
```

On server-side:

```
// idToken comes from the client app (shown above)
// ...
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // Retrieve or add some data in /users/{userId}/{document=**}
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```

As you can see, once I validate the accessToken and retrieve the uid, I can do anything on my database.

**References**

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the reason for going through a custom backend in this scenario? Why not get your client to directly access Firestore? Rules will be fully enforce in that case.

Comment: I need to perform some computations on the data retrieved from Firestore. Hence I prefer to have a backend that will do the hard work :)

Comment: I noticed https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges. I may find a way to pass the user's id through my backend to be matched with the security rules (like if my client directly accesses firestore)

Comment: That only works for Realtime Database. Firestore APIs in Admin SDK do not enforce rules at the moment.

Comment: Hum, so there is no way to have a backend service emulating a user to limit access to a server process, isn't it? A (bad) idea would be to initialize a firebaseApp with `databaseAuthVariableOverride: {uid: "user-uid"}` for each client request to my backend before requesting the database ...

Comment: Or, instead of using Admin SDK for server development, I can use the nodeJS SDK of Cloud Firestore in my server. Is there a way to pass through the credentials of the user from the client to the server and then to firebase ?

Comment: When it comes to Firestore in the server side, `Admin SDK == Firestore Node.js SDK`. Currently there's no way to scope Firestore down to an individual user in server-side. `databaseAuthVariableOverride` only works for Realtime Database. This requirement is in the Firebase/Firestore roadmap. It's just not supported as yet.

Comment: Thank you @HiranyaJayathilaka, I think it's clear :) I will implement my own security layer, along with verifyIdToken(). Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore - security rules for users within companies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183732/firestore-security-rules-for-users-within-companies)

Comment: Any update on whether this is available for Firestore yet?

Answer (score 27):

**The admin SDK will always have full access to the database.**

Since the client is never accessing Firebase directly, you should totally disable access to all documents. Your API will still have access

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
}
```

Comment: Tested: The Admin SDK doesn't work on Firestore Emulator unless the security rules all set to true: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1363#issuecomment-635834971

Comment: @AntonioOoi are you sure? I did not test on emulator but the live version is working fine with me

Comment: At least recent versions of the Firestore Emulator allow full access for the admin sdk when set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think after verify access token from client-side, you can send uid in resource of firestore-admin, and firestore rules would like this:

```
allow read, write: if request.resource.data.uid == userId;
```